# How to find the supremum of a brownian motion?

Tags: plotting, scripting, stochastic-calculus

I imagine this is quite simple but unable to find it, if I simulate a standard brownian motion, $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, with

```
B = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, 0.001}].
```

How would I then find and plot $S_t = \sup_\limits{0 \leq s \leq t} B_t$?

Comment: Does `m = TemporalData @ FoldList[{#2[[1]], Max[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]]} &, B["Path"]]; ListPlot[m]` do what you want?

Comment: You ask about maximum, not supremum. Maximum is attained, supremum not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the simulated points and then compute the maximum up to time t.

```
sup[simulation_,t_?NumericQ] := Max[TakeWhile[simulation["Path"], #[[1]] <= t &][[All, 2]]]
```

For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]; B = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, 0.001}];

Show[
  ListPlot[B],
  Plot[sup[B, t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black]
]
```

compares the maximum up to time t with the simulated points

[image]

Comment: +1. Thank you. Now I know more about  a realization of `WienerProcess`.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot, if you then wanted to plot functions of the two of them, say $D_t = S_t -B_t$? And if you wanted to amend it to a rolling maximum, $S_{r,t} = \sup_\limits{r \leq s \leq t} B_t$? Would you know how to go about that?

Comment: Yes, you can plot their difference, evaluating sup[B,t] at the times that appear in B["Path"]. See the documentation for TemporalData. For a rolling maximum, change sup to drop times in the path prior to r, before taking the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in such a way.

```
B = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, 0.001}];
f = Interpolation[B];
f[0,3]
```

> `0.273553`

```
m[x_?NumericQ] := First[NMaximize[{f[t], t >= 0 && t <= x}, t]];
m[0.3]
```

> `0.374923`

Unfortunately,

```
Plot[m[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

is very slow, so

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, m[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.2}]]
```

[image]